# How to understand /etc/mtab?

Tags: mount

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00 / ext3 rw 0 0
proc /proc proc rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
/dev/sda1 /boot ext3 rw 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw 0 0
none /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw 0 0
sunrpc /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs rpc_pipefs rw 0 0
```

What does the **6** columns mean?

Answer (score 18):

**mtab** lists currently mounted file systems and is used by the **mount** and **unmount** commands when you want to list your mounts or unmount all.  It's not used by the kernel, which maintains its own list (in `/proc/mounts` or `/proc/self/mounts`).  Its structure is the same as [fstab (see manpage)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab).

Separated by whitespace, its 6 columns are:

1. Mount device if applicable or "none"
2. Mount point
3. File system
4. Mount options
5. Used by the dump command, 0 to ignore*
6. Used by the fsck command (which order to check at boot), 0 to ignore*

*Note: mtab places a dummy value into the 5th and 6th columns so that the file retains the same structure as fstab.  These columns do not have any meaning in mtab.

Answer (score 4):

The columns in `/etc/mtab` are the same as `/etc/fstab`, except they represent currently mounted filesystems instead of those configured to be mounted by the installation or sysadmin.

You used to be able to `cat /etc/mtab > /etc/fstab` to save the current configuration of mounted filesystems for future boots.  I wouldn't recommend this these says, as`mtab` does not preserve mounts by label or UUID, such as `UUID=` or `LABEL=` in /etc/fstab, which is quite common in distros these days.  This will cause problems for devices which may not boot in the same order, such as external USB or eSATA drives.

`man fstab` will give you a description of the columns.

Comment: I don't see how it answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

The `/etc/mtab` file shares the same structure as `/etc/fstab`. According to [this site](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html) the 5th and 6th column in `/etc/fstab` are used to store "Dump and fsck options". The 5th column is used to determine if dumping of the partition should be made, and the 6th to decide if an fsck must be processed on the partition.

In `/etc/mtab`, however, this two options loose their sense. Indeed, these two options are used when mounting the partitions, and `/etc/mtab` lists the partitions that are already mounted. If I understand it correctly, these option are not useful in `/etc/mtab`. They may be here for compatibility reasons with `/etc/fstab`, as the content of `/etc/mtab` must be directly usable in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Good point about columns 5 and 6 being meaningless in /etc/mtab, but being there so that it can be pasted into /etc/fstab and be compatible

Answer (score 2):

The /etc/mtab file is the list of mounted file systems it is maintained by the mount and unmount programs. It's format is similar to the fstab file The columns arw

- **device** the device or remote filesystem that is mounted.
- **mountpoint**  the place in the filesystem the device was mounted.
- **filesystemtype** the type of filesystem mounted.
- **options** the mount options for the filesystem
- **dump**   used by dump to decide if the filesystem needs dumping.
- **fsckorder** used by fsck to detrmine the fsck pass to use.

Check the [fstab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab) man page.